# Multiple if vs else if which is faster

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a test which is faster in code executing.

#### Situation 1

```
int a=2;

if(a==1)
{
//code here
}
if(a==2)
{
//code here
}
if(a==3)
{
//code here
}
```

#### Situation 2

```
int a=2;

if(a==1)
{
//code here
}
else if(a==2)
{
//code here
}
else if(a==3)
{
//code here
}
```

In situation 1, 'int a' is  always different value inside if statements

Comment: `switch` would probably be faster, but more important is the fact those two pieces of code do different things. If your `code here` included `a = 3` what do you want to happen?

Comment: I think you should leave this for compiler and focus on readability. I would recomend using switch here.

Comment: when you ran the code and measured how long it took, which was faster?

Comment: I dont notice any difference in execution time. 0.3 millisecond for both examples

Comment: @DimChris So then you already know the answer to your question.

Comment: 1. [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) and 2. http://benchmarkdotnet.org/ .

Comment: @JeroenMostert A classic from Eric.  I would [add this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) to the conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of if or if else statements I would recommend a switch statement like this:

```
int a = 2;
     switch (a)
      {
      case 1:

        break;
      case 2:

        break;
      case 3:

        break;
     }
```

Reference: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The second code block can be faster because the first one always tests every condition. The second one stops testing after it finds a match.